# Can I alter the After= of an active systemd unit?

Tags: linux, systemd

I have an NFS filesystem that contains ext4 filesystem images. A Linux box mounts one of those, via an implicit `/dev/loop<n>`. But when systemd reboots, it apparently shuts down NFS before attempting to unmount the child loopback filesystem. It fails to unmount the loopback and therefore fails to reboot, leaving a series of these messages on the console:

`systemd-journald: Failed to send WATCHDOG=1 notification message: Transport endpoint is not connected`

I want this system to reboot without me pressing the hardware power switch. I think it would do that if I could tell systemd about the dependency between the loopback and the parent filesystem. Is this possible? I tried `systemctl set-property dev-loop0.device After=rawparents-1.mount`, but it says `Unknown assignment After=rawparents-1.mount.`

[This bug report](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2814) says that systemd does not automatically understand dependencies involving loopback devices, and it will not gain the ability to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to define drop-in files even if the unit doesn’t have any configuration files. That is:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/dev-loop0.device.d/

cat > /etc/systemd/system/dev-loop0.device.d/after.conf << 'EOF'
[Unit]
After=rawparents-1.mount
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
```

Afterwards, check that the file was processed with `systemctl show -p After dev-loop0.device`.

Answer (score 1):

Ive never used the set-property subcommand, but you can do `systemctl edit SERVICE` to add overrides to a unit.

Similarly, `systemctl cat SERVICE` is very useful, and also includes commentary as to the file(s) involved.

Comment: The parent mount, child mount, and loop device units in systemd don't have any configuration files for them. So both `edit` and `cat` fail.